# Can the $2$-norm of $x$ be arbitrarily larger than the norms of $A$ and $b$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, normed-spaces

Assume that $x$ is a solution to the linear system $Ax=b$, where

- $A$ is a $n\times m$  matrix, with $m > n$
- $x$ is an *m-dimensional* column vector
- $b$ is an *n-dimensional* column vector.

Can the $2$-norm of $x$ be arbitrarily larger than the norms of $A$ and $b$?

Comment: $m \times n$???

Comment: @Kaveh If $A$ is $m \times n$, then the equation only makes sense if $x$ is an $n$-dimensional column vector and $b$ is $m$ dimensional.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I made an error. I fixed it by modifying my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made an error in your question. I assume that $x \in \Bbb R^n$ and $b \in \Bbb R^m$.

In short, the answer is yes. If the solution to $Ax = b$ is unique, then we must have
$$
x = A^+ b = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb,
$$
where $A^+$ denotes the [Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse)  of $A$. Note that the induced $2$-norm of $A^+$ satisfies $\|A^+\| = 1/\sigma_\min$, and the associated inequality
$$
\|x\| \leq \|A^+\| \cdot \|b\|
$$
is *tight*, which is to say that there exists an $b$ for which $Ax = b$ has an exact solution and this inequality is an equality.

If $\kappa(A)$ denotes the [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of $A$, then we can write this inequality in terms of $\|A\|$. In particular, we have
$$
\|x\| \leq \frac{\kappa(A) \cdot \|b\|}{\|A\|}.
$$